# Javascript Next Day Delivery Timer

Tags: javascript, datetime

On our site, we would like to display

"Want it by **Thursday 8th December**? Order within 4 hrs 55 mins

At the moment it says:
"NEXT DAY UK DELIVERY, order within 4 hrs 55 mins", which is confusing.

How do we generate the next day in script and how do we skip Saturdays and Sundays? The delivery cutoff is 2pm Monday-Friday. The one on this site works well: https://www.yumi.com/

Here is the script we currently have:

```js
function getTimeLeft() {
  var now = moment();
  var deadline = now.clone().hour(14).minute(0).second(0);
  if (now.isAfter(deadline)) {
    var tomorrow = moment(new Date()).add(1, 'days').hour(14).minute(0).second(0);
    //alert(tomorrow);
   // console.log(tomorrow.diff(now, "hours") + ' hrs, ' + (tomorrow.diff(now, "minutes") % 60) + ' mins');
    // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = "<b>NEXT DAY UK DELIVERY</b>, order within<b>" + " " +tomorrow.diff(now, "hours") + ' hrs ' +  (tomorrow.diff(now, "minutes") % 60) + ' mins' + "</b> ";

  } else {
//     console.log(deadline.diff(now, "hours") + ' hrs, ' + (deadline.diff(now, "minutes") % 60) + ' mins');
     document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = "<b>NEXT DAY UK DELIVERY</b>, order within<b>" + " " +deadline.diff(now, "hours") + ' hrs ' + (deadline.diff(now, "minutes") % 60) + ' mins' + " </b>";
  }
} 

getTimeLeft();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo3"></div>
```

This was built by developers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
function returnDeliveryDate() {
  switch (moment().clone().add(1, 'days').day()) {
    case 6:
      return moment().clone().add(3, 'days');
    case 0:
      return moment().clone().add(2, 'days');
    default:
      return moment().clone().add(1, 'days');
  }
}

function getTimeLeft() {
  var now = moment();
  var deadline = now.clone().hour(14).minute(0).second(0);
  var expectedDeliveryDate = 
  returnDeliveryDate().hour(14).minute(0).second(0);
  
if (now.isAfter(deadline)) {
    document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML =
    'delivery in,' +
    expectedDeliveryDate.format() +
    'order within' +
    ' ' +
    expectedDeliveryDate.diff(now, 'hours') +
   ' hrs ' +
   (expectedDeliveryDate.diff(now, 'minutes') % 60) +
   ' mins';
   } else {
   document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML = 'delivery in,' +
   deadline.format() +
   'order within' +
   ' ' +
   deadline.diff(now, 'hours') +
  ' hrs ' +
  (deadline.diff(now, 'minutes') % 60) +
  ' mins';;
}
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo3"></div>
```

I basically left your code as is except of the tomorrow date part. All you have to do now is to format the date as you need and maybe change the message text.

Hope this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm struggling with this. This is what our product-template file looks like now

```
<div class="page-width" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" id="ProductSection-{{ section.id }}" data-section-id="{{ section.id }}" data-section-type="product" data-enable-history-state="true" data-ajax="{{ section.settings.enable_ajax }}" data-stock="{{ section.settings.stock_enable }}">
  {% assign product_image_size = '680x680' %}

  <meta itemprop="name" content="{{ product.title }}">
  <meta itemprop="url" content="{{ shop.url }}{{ product.url }}">
  <meta itemprop="image" content="{{ product.featured_image.src | img_url: '600x600' }}">
  {%- if settings.product_vendor_enable -%} 
    <meta itemprop="brand" content="{{ product.vendor }}">
  {%- endif -%}

  {% comment %}
    Get first variant, or deep linked one
  {% endcomment %}
  {% assign current_variant = product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}
  <div class='sv_breadcrubs'>
    {% include 'breadcrumbs' %}
    </div>
    <div class="grid product-single">
   <div class="slider-gallery grid__item {% if product.images.size > 1 %}medium-up--three-fifths{% else %}medium-up--one-half{% endif %} choco_product_img">
      <div class="photos">
        <div class="photos__item photos__item--main">
          <div class="product-single__photo" id="ProductPhoto">
            {% assign featured_image = current_variant.featured_image | default: product.featured_image %}
            <a href="{{ featured_image | img_url: '1024x1024' }}" class="js-modal-open-product-modal" id="ProductPhotoLink-{{ section.id }}">
              <img src="{{ featured_image | img_url: product_image_size }}" alt="{{ featured_image.alt | escape }}" id="ProductPhotoImg-{{ section.id }}">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        {% if product.images.size > 1 %}
          <div class="photos__item photos__item--thumbs">
            <div class="product-single__thumbnails{% unless product.images.size > 2 %} product-single__thumbnails--static{% endunless %}" id="ProductThumbs-{{ section.id }}">
              {% for image in product.images %}
                <div class="product-single__thumbnail-item {% if image == featured_image %} is-active {% endif %}">
                  <a href="{{ image.src | img_url: product_image_size }}" data-zoom="{{ image.src | img_url: '1024x1024' }}" class="product-single__thumbnail product-single__thumbnail-{{ section.id }}">
                    <img src="{{ image.src | img_url: '160x160' }}" alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}">
                  </a>
                </div>
              {% endfor %}
            </div>
          </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% if product.images.size > 2 %}
          {% comment %}
            Add SVG icon snippets to an object for custom slider arrows
          {% endcomment %}
          <script>
            {% capture arrow_left %}{% include 'icon-arrow-left' %}{% endcapture %}
            {% capture arrow_right %}{% include 'icon-arrow-right' %}{% endcapture %}
            {% capture arrow_up %}{% include 'icon-arrow-up' %}{% endcapture %}
            {% capture arrow_down %}{% include 'icon-arrow-down' %}{% endcapture %}
            var sliderArrows = {
              left: {{ arrow_left | json }},
              right: {{ arrow_right | json }},
              up: {{ arrow_up | json }},
              down: {{ arrow_down | json }}
            }
          </script>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </div>
<!--<div id="desktop-images" class="grid__item medium-up--three-fifths"></div>
 <script>
  var p = {{ product | json }};
  //console.log(p.featured_image);
  var array_images = p.images;
  $.each(array_images , function(index, val) { 
  //console.log(index, val)
$("#desktop-images").append("<img src="+val+" width='350px' height='350px' class='pro-img'/>");
   
});
</script> -->
    <div class="grid__item {% if product.images.size > 1 %}medium-up--two-fifths{% else %}medium-up--one-half{% endif %} choco_desc_panel" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
      <div class="product-single__info-wrapper">
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="{{ shop.currency }}">
     
        <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/{% if product.available %}InStock{% else %}OutOfStock{% endif %}">
      
       
        <div class="product-single__meta small--text-center">
          {% if settings.product_vendor_enable %}
            <p class="product-single__vendor">{{ product.vendor }}</p>
          {% endif %}

          <h1 itemprop="name" class="product-single__title">{{ product.title }}</h1>
          
<span class="stamped-product-reviews-badge stamped-main-badge" data-id="{{ product.id }}" data-product-title="{{ product.title | escape }}" data-product-type="{{ product.type }}" style="display: block;" onclick="$('#gift_tab').click();$('#gift_tab').addClass('block');"></span>
          
                
                 
          <ul class="product-single__meta-list list--no-bullets list--inline">
            <li id="ProductSaleTag-{{ section.id }}" class="{% unless product.compare_at_price > product.price %}hide{% endunless %}">
              <div class="product-tag">
                {{ 'products.product.on_sale' | t }}
              </div>
            </li>
             {% if product.compare_at_price_max > product.price %}
              <li>
                <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.regular_price' | t }}</span>
                <s id="ComparePrice-{{ section.id }}" class="product-single__price product-single__price--compare">
                  {{ current_variant.compare_at_price | money }}
                </s>
              </li>
            {% endif %}
            <li>
              {% unless product.compare_at_price_max > product.price %}
                <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.regular_price' | t }}</span>
              {% endunless %}
              <span id="ProductPrice-{{ section.id }}" class="product-single__price" itemprop="price" content="{{ current_variant.price | divided_by: 100.00 }}">
                {{ current_variant.price | money }}
                
              </span>
             </li>             
             <!-- Swym Wishlist Plus EPI Button-->
  <button data-with-epi="true" class="swym-button swym-add-to-wishlist-view-product product_{{product.id}}" data-swaction="addToWishlist" data-product-id="{{product.id | json}}" data-variant-id="{{product.variants[0].id}}" data-product-url="{{ shop.url }}{{ product.url }}"></button>
  <!-- Swym Wishlist Plus EPI Button-->


            <!-- <p class="vendor">  {{product.vendor}} </p>-->
           
          {% for t in product.tags %}
          {% if t contains 'MIX & MATCH' %}
            <li><a class="mix-pro" href="https://martinschocolatier.co.uk/collections/mix-and-match">MIX & MATCH - 3 FOR 2</a></li>
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
           
            {% if section.settings.stock_enable %}
              <li>
                <span id="ProductStock-{{ section.id }}" class="product-single__stock {% unless current_variant.inventory_management and current_variant.inventory_quantity < 10 and current_variant.inventory_quantity > 0 or  current_variant.inventory_management and current_variant.inventory_quantity <= 0 and current_variant.incoming %} hide{% endunless %}">
                  {% if current_variant.inventory_management %}
                    {% if current_variant.inventory_quantity < 10 and current_variant.inventory_quantity > 0 %}
                      {% assign qty = current_variant.inventory_quantity %}
                      {{ 'products.product.stock_available' | t: count: qty }}
                    {% elsif current_variant.inventory_quantity == 0 or current_variant.inventory_quantity < 0 and current_variant.incoming %}
                      {% if current_variant.available %}
                        {% assign date = current_variant.next_incoming_date | date: "%B %-d, %Y" %}
                        {{ 'products.product.will_not_ship_until' | t: date: date  }}
                      {% else %}
                        {% assign date = current_variant.next_incoming_date | date: "%B %-d, %Y" %}
                        {{ 'products.product.will_be_in_stock_after' | t: date: date  }}
                      {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                  {% endif %}
                </span>
              </li>
            {% endif %}
    
          </ul>
                  
        </div>
       
         <div class='cart_wish'>
           <div class='choco_cart_form_custom'>
        <form action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="product-form_custom" id="AddToCartForm">

          {% unless product.options.size == 1 and product.variants[0].title == 'Default Title' %}
            {% for option in product.options_with_values %}
              <div class="selector-wrapper js product-form__item">
                <label {% if option.name == 'default' %}class="label--hidden" {% endif %}for="SingleOptionSelector-{{ section.id }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}">{{ option.name }}</label>
                <select class="single-option-selector single-option-selector-{{ section.id }} product-form__input"
                  id="SingleOptionSelector-{{ forloop.index0 }}"
                  data-name="{{ option.name }}"
                  data-index="option{{ forloop.index }}">
                  {% for value in option.values %}
                    <option value="{{ value | escape }}"{% if option.selected_value == value %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ value }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
                </select>
              </div>
            {% endfor %}
          {% endunless %}
           <div style=" display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; ">
          <select name="id" id="ProductSelect-{{ section.id }}" class="product-form__variants no-js">
            {% for variant in product.variants %}
              <option {% if variant == current_variant %} selected="selected" {% endif %} data-sku="{{ variant.sku }}" value="{{ variant.id }}" {% unless variant.available %} disabled="disabled" {% endunless %}>
                {% if variant.available %}
                  {{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money_with_currency }}
                {% else %}
                  {{ variant.title }} - {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
                {% endif %}
              </option>
            {% endfor %}
          </select>

            <div class="product-form--quantity-wrapper-custom">
                <div class="product-form__item product-form__item--quantity" style="height: 53px;">
                  <label for="Quantity">{{ 'products.product.quantity' | t }}</label>
                  <input type="number" id="Quantity" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" class="product-form__input product-form__quantity">
                </div>
{%  if product.tags contains 'vegan' %}
              <div class="kaching-icon-block" style="width: 100%;" data-block-id="05d1c5c5-0cc9-4e22-a15f-fa3a2fc29425"></div>{% endif %}
            </div>
  
 {% unless product.content contains 'zakeke-design-tag' %}

{% endunless %}     
 {% if product.tags contains 'zakeke-product' or product.content contains 'zakeke-product-tag' %}
   <button id="zakeke-product-button" style="width: 100%;" class="btn product-form__cart-submit">
 <span>Personalise</span>
 </button>
 <input name="zakeke-product-id" type="hidden" value="{{ product.id }}">
 <script>
  (function () {
    function findAncestor (el, sel) {
      while ((el = el.parentElement) && !((el.matches || el.matchesSelector).call(el,sel)));
      return el;
    }

    var btn = document.querySelector('#zakeke-product-button');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      var form = findAncestor(btn, 'form');
      if (!form || !form.reportValidity()) {
        return;
      }
      var pid = form.querySelector('input[name="zakeke-product-id"]').value;
      
      var originalAction = form.action;
      form.action = (window.zakekeUrl || '/apps/zakeke') + '?pid=' + pid;

      window.onpageshow = function(event) {
          if (event.persisted) {
              form.action = originalAction;
          }
      };
      form.submit();
    });
  })();
  </script>
 {% endif %}       

        
          <div class="product-form__item product-form__item--submit" style=" padding-left: 0px !important; padding-right: 0px !important; flex: 100%;margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: 0; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px">
            <button type="submit"
              name="add"
              id="AddToCart-{{ section.id }}"
              class="btn btn--full product-form__cart-submit_custom{% unless current_variant.available %}  {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }} {% endunless %}"
              {% unless current_variant.available %}disabled="disabled"{% endunless %}>
              <span id="AddToCartText-{{ section.id }}">
                {% unless current_variant.available %}
                  {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
                {% else %}

                  {{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}

         {% endunless %}       
              </span>
            </button>
          </div></div>
                </form>
    <div style="border:1px solid #ccc;margin-bottom: 10px;padding-top: 10px;text-align:center"> 
                       <div style="display: inline-block; " class="">
                    <label style="display:inline; float:none" for="effectiveAppsEGWATC">
                      <input style="-webkit-appearance: checkbox; float:none; vertical-align: middle;" type="checkbox" id="effectiveAppsEGWATC" name="effectiveAppsEGWATC" onchange="window.effectiveAppsEGWModal.open();"> 
                      <span><strong style="text-transform: initial; font-size: 14px; color: black;"><img src = "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0566/7389/4570/files/giftbox.png?v=1666338627"width="50" height="50" style="vertical-align:middle">Add a PERSONAL message and GIFT WRAP to this order from £2.00
                      
</strong></span></label><br /><br /> </div></div>
<!--         <div id="ping-app"></div> -->


 <!--<span class="klarna"><img class="klarnalogo" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0566/7389/4570/files/2021-08-19_3.png?v=1629369718">Make 3 payments of
          <span id="ProductPriceklarna-{{ section.id }}" class="klarna-price" itemprop="price" content="{{ current_variant.price | divided_by: 100.00 }}">
                {{ current_variant.price | money }}
              </span>.No fees. <a class="learn" href="">Learn more</a></span>-->
        




<!-- Placement v2 -->
<!--<klarna-placement
  data-key="top-strip-promotion-auto-size"
  data-locale="en-GB"
></klarna-placement> -->
<!-- end Placement -->

            <!-- Placement afterpay -->
<!--div style="border:1px solid #ccc;margin-bottom: 10px;text-align:center; padding-left: 20px; padding-right:20px";>
<afterpay-placement 
    data-locale="en_GB"
    data-currency="GBP" 
    data-amount="400"
  data-logtype ="lockup">-->
  
    </afterpay-placement></div>
  
    <!-- end Placement -->
       

<!-- Placement v2 -->
<klarna-placement
data-key="credit-promotion-auto-size" 
data-locale="en-GB"
data-purchase-amount="{{ current_variant.price }}"> 
</klarna-placement> 
<!-- end Placement -->
  

   <div class='wishlist_div'>
     <div id="drop-hint-div"><div id="dropahint_wrapper"></div>
</div>
        {% include 'wishlist-product' %}
           
        </div> 
        {{ 'wish-list.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
        <div class="del">
 
          <li class="desc_hd" style='float:right;padding:3px;'><!--<span><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0566/7389/4570/files/2021-08-19_1.png?v=1629369689"  title="My image" /></span>
         <!-- <span class='order_bytime'>Order within <label>--><!--<div id="pro_timer"> </div> <!--</label> for <label>UK NEXT DAY DELIVERY</label>
              </span>-->
            
           
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="timer" style="border:1px solid #ccc;margin-top:74px">  <p id="demo3"></p> </div>

        <div id="pro_timer"> </div>
        
        <div class="rte product-single__description" itemprop="description">
          <div class='desc_hd'>Detailed Info <span id='desc_tab'>-</span></div>
          <div class='dv_choco_desc'>
          {{ product.description }}
          </div>
      <div>
                    

             

{% assign count = product.metafields.custom.ingredients | size %}
<script>console.log('anctest ','{{ count }}');</script>

 {% if count > 1 %} 
<div class='ingredients-new'>Ingredients<span id='ingredients_tab'>+</span></div>
<div class='ingredients dv_choco_desc'>Ingredients<span id='ingredients_tab'>+</span></div> <div class='dv_choco_ingredients'> 
   {{ product.metafields.custom.ingredients }} </div> {% endif %}
          </div>
<div>

          <div class='gift-wrap-new'>Product Reviews<span id='gift_tab'>+</span></div>
          <div class='dv_choco_gift'>
    <!--Stamped - Begin Main Widget -->
<div 
id="stamped-main-widget"   
data-product-id="{{ product.id }}"   
data-name="{{ product.title | escape }}"   
data-url="{{ shop.url }}{{ product.url }}"   
data-image-url="{{ product.featured_image | product_img_url: "large" |replace: '?', '%3F' | replace: '&','%26'}}" 
data-description="{{ product.description | escape }}"   
data-product-sku="{{product.handle}}"
data-product-title="{{product.title}}" 
data-product-type="{{product.type}}">   
{{product.metafields.stamped.reviews}}   
</div>
<!-- Stamped - End Main Widget -->
          </div></div></div></div>
        <!--<div class='gift-wrap' style="display: block !important;">Gift Wrapping<span id='gift_tab'></span>
                 
             </div>
        
          <div class='dv_choco_gift'>
          <div id="shopify-product-gift" class='choco_gift' data-id="{{product.id}}">{{ product.gift }}</div>
          </div>--->
{% comment %}
        {% if section.settings.social_sharing_products %}
          {% include 'social-sharing', share_title: product.title, share_permalink: product.url, share_image: product %}
        {% endif %}
        {% endcomment %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<style>
  span#timer-mins:after {content: "for NEXT Day DELIVERY";}

#demo3:before {
content: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0566/7389/4570/files/2021-08-19_1.png?v=1629369689);
    top: 3px;
    position: relative;
    right: 3px;

}
  span#timer-secs {
    display: none;
}
  .main-timer {
    top: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
  div#pro_timer {
    
    width: 100%;
   
}
.timer-content {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    /* text-align: center; */
    top: 12px;
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    justify-content: center;
}
  i.spr-icon.spr-icon-star {
    color: orange;
}
  span.spr-starrating.spr-summary-starrating {
    display: none;
}
  h2.spr-header-title {
    display: none;
}
  .dv_choco_gift {
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    border-top: #cecece solid 1px;
}
  a.mix-pro {
    color: black;
}
</style>
<script>


</script>
<script> 
   $(".dv_choco_ingredients").hide();
    $(".dv_choco_gift").hide();
    $(".dv_choco_review").hide();
    $(".dv_choco_shipping").hide();
$("#desc_tab").click(function(){
    if($(this).html() == "-"){
        $(this).html("+");
    }
    else{
        $(this).html("-");
    }
    $(".dv_choco_desc").slideToggle();
});
  
  $("#review_tab").click(function(){
    if($(this).html() == "-"){
        $(this).html("+");
    }
    else{
        $(this).html("-");
    }
    $(".dv_choco_review").slideToggle();
});
   $("#shipping_tab").click(function(){
    if($(this).html() == "-"){
        $(this).html("+");
    }
    else{
        $(this).html("-");
    }
    $(".dv_choco_shipping").slideToggle();
});
   $("#ingredients_tab").click(function(){
    if($(this).html() == "-"){
        $(this).html("+");
    }
    else{
        $(this).html("-");
    }
    $(".dv_choco_ingredients").slideToggle();
});
   $("#gift_tab").click(function(){
    if($(this).html() == "-"){
        $(this).html("+");
    }
    else{
        $(this).html("-");
    }
    $(".dv_choco_gift").slideToggle();
});
  
  
</script>

<script>
   $( document ).ready(function() {
    var len = $(".product-single #desktop-images .pro-img").length;
    if(len == 1)
    {
    $(".product-single #desktop-images .pro-img").css({"width":"100%","height":"50%"});
    }
  });
</script>

<script>
function returnDeliveryDate() {
  switch (moment().clone().add(1, 'days').day()) {
    case 6:
      return moment().clone().add(3, 'days');
    case 0:
      return moment().clone().add(2, 'days');
    default:
      return moment().clone().add(1, 'days');
  }
}

function getTimeLeft() {
  var now = moment();
  var deadline = now.clone().hour(14).minute(0).second(0);
  var expectedDeliveryDate = 
  returnDeliveryDate().hour(14).minute(0).second(0);
  
if (now.isAfter(deadline)) {
    document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML =
    'delivery in,' +
    expectedDeliveryDate.format() +
    'order within' +
    ' ' +
    expectedDeliveryDate.diff(now, 'hours') +
   ' hrs ' +
   (expectedDeliveryDate.diff(now, 'minutes') % 60) +
   ' mins';
   } else {
   document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML = 'delivery in,' +
   deadline.format() +
   'order within' +
   ' ' +
   deadline.diff(now, 'hours') +
  ' hrs ' +
  (deadline.diff(now, 'minutes') % 60) +
  ' mins';;
}
   }
 
</script>

{% unless product == empty %}
  <script type="application/json" id="ProductJson-{{ section.id }}">
    {{ product | json }}
  </script>
  {% if section.settings.stock_enable %}
    <script type="application/json" id="VariantJson-{{ section.id }}">
      [
        {% for variant in product.variants %}
          {
             "incoming": {{ variant.incoming | default: false | json }},
             "next_incoming_date": {{ variant.next_incoming_date | date: format: 'month_day_year' | json }}
          }{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}
        {% endfor %}
      ]
    </script>
  {% endif %}
{% endunless %}

{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Product pages",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "id": "enable_ajax",
        "label": "Stay on current page when item is added to cart",
        "default": true
      },
      {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "id": "stock_enable",
        "label": "Show stock when less than 10 products available",
        "default": false
      },
      {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "id": "social_sharing_products",
        "label": "Enable product sharing",
        "default": true
      }
    ]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

Comment: If this is not an answer please remove it and add it as part of your question description